# Compare array to reference array and remove duplicates

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I can't understand how to rewrite this expression in more "swift" and efficient way:

```
for result in results {
  var isExists = false

  for ref in referenceArray {
      if result.id == ref.id {
          isExists = true
          break
      }
  }

  if isExists == false {
      filteredResults.append(result)
  }
}
```

I tried this:

```
filteredResults = results.filter { result in
   referenceArray.contains { $0.id != result.id }
}
```

But it gives me empty array.

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't a `Set` work better for this sort of exclusivity check? I would double-check that `.contains` returns `true` in some of the cases. You might be getting any empty `filteredResults` because the closure passed to `filter` is always returns `false`.

Comment: Please write an MCVE. Provide sample input and actual vs. expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it sounds like you want to do something like this:

> Given a set of items `A` and set of items `B`, create a set of items `C` with only the items that are in `B` and *not* in `A`.

To paraphrase, I think you're looking for the "new" things in `B` that don't already exist in `A`.

If this is what you're trying to do you can use a [`Set`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set). This is a trivial example with `Int`s, but hopefully it'll help:

```
let setA = Set([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
let setB = Set([2,4,6,8,10,13])

// Only the values that overlap both sets
let evens = setA.intersection(setB)                // {6, 10, 2, 4, 8}

// Only the values that do not overlap both sets
let odds = setA.symmetricDifference(setB)          // {9, 5, 7, 3, 1, 13}  

// All unique elements in both sets
let uniqueToBoth = setA.union(setB)                // {13, 10, 2, 4, 9, 5, 6, 7, 3, 1, 8}

// Only elements unique to B
let uniqueToB = setB.subtracting(setA)             // {13}
```

Comment: You're right, I guess I have to go with the set, thank you.